# Howto update my existing mobile air app in the ios store with a new cordova app

Tags: ios, apache, cordova, mobile, air

I want to update an existing mobile air app in the ios store with a new cordova app but the id contains air.com... I want this air prefix removed. Can I change the id when updating an app?

Answer (score 0):

The id is part of the identifier that Apple uses to differentiate apps.

If you change the id, the app store will consider it a completely new app, not an update.

Also, not sure how your identifiers are setup in your Developer account for your certificates, but changing the id could break that too.

Comment: new id will require new provisioning profiles as it's a new app

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So all users have to download and install a new app from the store if I change from adobe air mobile to cordova? There is no way to upgrade to cordova using a different ID? Has anybody ever contacted Apple to request an ID change?